# Apache POI XSSFSimpleShape rectangle and triangle

Tags: apache-poi

Want to create triangle and rectangle like below image. Some sample code I'm trying to implement. But did not meet my requirement.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\sample.xlsx");
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet");
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(4); // Creating a row
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1); // Creating a cell
XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();


XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(500, 200, 0, 0, 1, 10, 5, 11);
anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);

XSSFSimpleShape rectangle = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);

//rounded rectangle
rectangle.setShapeType(26);
rectangle.setFillColor(180,180,180);

XSSFClientAnchor anchor1 = new XSSFClientAnchor(10, 10, 100, 100, 1, 10, 2, 11);
XSSFSimpleShape triangle = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor1);
//triangle
triangle.setShapeType(3);   
triangle.setFillColor(255,0,0);

wb.write(os);
wb.close();
os.close();
```

Wanted result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code works and creates a gray rounded rectangle and a red triangle.

What you needs to know now, is how to place the shapes on the cells of the sheet using the [XSSFClientAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFClientAnchor.html). So what exactly means `dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, col1, row1, col2, row2` in the constructor?

`dx1` means how many English Metric Units (`EMU`s) away from `col1` does the shape start

`dy1` means how many English Metric Units (`EMU`s) away from `row1` does the shape start

`dx2` means how many English Metric Units (`EMU`s) away from `col2` does the shape end

`dy2` means how many English Metric Units (`EMU`s) away from `row2` does the shape end

`col1` means what column (0-based) is the start column of the shape

`row1` means what row (0-based) is the start row of the shape

`col2` means what column (0-based) is the end column of the shape

`row2` means what row (0-based) is the end row of the shape

For working with the `EMU`s [org.apache.poi.util.Units](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html) was made.

And you need to know how to flip a shape. This is not supported in high level `XSSFSimpleShape` up to now. But using the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes, it is possible:

```
shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);
```

The `shape` is a `XSSFSimpleShape` here.

If you knows that, you can do:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

class CreateXSSFSimpleShapes {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet");

   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(
    0, //dx1 = 0
    0, //dy1 = 0
    0, //dx2 = 0
    0, //dy2 = 0
    1, //col1 = 1 (col B)
    10,//row1 = 10 (row 11) 
    5, //col2 = 5 (col F)
    11 //row2 = 11 (row 12)
   );
   anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
   XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
   //rounded rectangle
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.ROUND_RECT);
   shape.setFillColor(180,180,180);

   anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(
    0, //dx1 = 0
    0, //dy1 = 0
    Units.pixelToEMU(20), //dx2 = 20px away from left border of col2
    0, //dy2 = 0
    1, //col1 = 1 (col B)
    10,//row1 = 10 (row 11) 
    1, //col2 = 1 (col B)
    11 //row2 = 11 (row 12)
   );
   shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
   //blue triangle
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.TRIANGLE);   
   shape.setFillColor(0,0,255);

   anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(
    Units.pixelToEMU(20), //dx1 = 20px away from left border of col1
    0, //dy1 = 0
    Units.pixelToEMU(40), //dx2 = 40px away from left border of col2
    0, //dy2 = 0
    1, //col1 = 1 (col B)
    10,//row1 = 10 (row 11) 
    1, //col2 = 1 (col B)
    11 //row2 = 11 (row 12)
   );
   shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
   //red triangle
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.TRIANGLE);   
   shape.setFillColor(255,0,0);
   //flip shape vertical
   shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```